# Maintaining the order for file creation in hadoop - hdfs

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have a code which creates files in Hadoop dfs. The names given to these files are incremental (like 1,2,3 etc). This is done to maintain proper ordering of the files created. But when I look at the files these files are shown in a random order (may be due to variation in the file size).

I also have a code which takes as a input directory path and reads all the files under it. But my concern is, the files are not read in the same order as they are written (Reads back in the order same as seen on the UI).

How should I achieve this? Is there something that I can do while writing the files itself to preserve the order or do I need to handle it while reading ?

**org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus.getModificationTime()** gives long value indicating last time the file was modified. This can be used to order the files. But does not seems to be a feasible solution as I may have any number of files.

Do we have any API class which can do this for me or even preserve ordering ?

Answer (score 0):

You can order files from a directory just like this:

```
File file = new File( path );
File[] list = file.listFiles();   

    Arrays.sort(list, new Comparator<File>(){
        public int compare(File f1, File f2)
        {
            return Long.valueOf(f1.lastModified()).compareTo(f2.lastModified());
        } });
```

Now list contains all those files shorted by the lastModified. Perhaps you may need to order them in a differt fashion such us by name or a reg. expressions that takes that 1,2,3 seg. number.

As for managing the way files are written, beats me. I can't think of anything but creating a synchronized method which could create a bottleneck in your app.

I hope this helps!